# pytesseract AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have just installed pytesseract  and trying to import it into my python file.

My code [(here is the site I am referring to)](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/10/using-tesseract-ocr-python/):

```
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract
import argparse
import cv2
import os
```

Here is the complete error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ROCKSTAR/Downloads/TRIVIA/getAnswers.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pytesseract
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pytesseract import (
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 21, in <module>
numpy_installed = True if find_loader('numpy') is not None else False
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 488, in find_loader
    return spec.loader
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'loader'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Check for more info https://github.com/pallets/flask/issues/1011

Comment: Where will I find helpers.py?

Comment: You should place a bug report here: https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract/issues; As this is something they (as developers) need to fix. If you need the library urgently, you can use a different version of Python > 3.4 or 2.7, or monkey patch find_loader function in pytesseract.py at line 12. Or you can set `numpy_installed` manually, to True or to False.